# How to get the position of a row in ListView without using OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I have an app with a SQLite database and a ListView, which maps the database by using SimpleCursorAdapter. I read a String with a barcode-scanner, using TextWatcher. Now I want to pick out the scanned String in ListView and put the related row on top. Therefor I think I need the position of the row. How can I get the position of the scanned string in the ListView? Or is there any other way to manage that?

Comment: you can do that from your adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//mAdapter is your listview adapter
public int getRowInListView(String barcodedString){
    for(int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++){
        String s = mAdapter.getItem(i).toString();
        //if you have a custom object in you adapter instead use this 
        String s = ((MyObject)mAdapter.getItem(i)).getBarcode();

        if(s.equals(barcodedString))
            return i;
    }

    return -1
}
```